# Set Face Font in ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, font-face

I am unable to set FontFace in a list view.

In buttons or textviews,  I am able to set font like

Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf");
                button.setTypeface(typeface);

How can I do it for the String appearing in ListView as well?

**XML**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:elevation="10dp">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Java**

```
 ListView listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    // Defined Array values to show in ListView
    String[] values = new String[] { "string 1", "string 2", ..... }
    };



    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    // ListView Item Click Listener
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            // ListView Clicked item value
            String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            gp.setphrase(itemValue);
            Intent i = new Intent(PhraseListView.this,record.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }});}
```

:(

Comment: Here's a hint. The `TextView` you wish to assign your `Typeface` to exists within `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

Comment: Got it, Trying! :)

Comment: Awesome! It might be helpful to know that internally, Android uses  `android.R.id.text1` as the `resourceId` for the `TextView`.

Comment: in oncreate 
`final Typeface typeface2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf");`
after setting adapter 
`TextView text1= (TextView)this.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        text1.setTypeface(typeface2); `
dint work
the problem is of this or view in this. could you help please

Comment: you cannot modify the textview which will be used by the adapter for view creation , although can create a layout , add font file to textview , mention the textview id while adapter creation and done

Comment: I tried .. 
`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.simplelist, R.id.simplelistid, values);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

       TextView text1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.simplelistid);
        Typeface typeface2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf");
        text1.setTypeface(typeface2);`

the simplelist.XML file has one TextView tag wid id simplelistid

DIDNT WORK :(

Comment: follow this link https://developer.android.com/preview/features/fonts-in-xml.html to add your font in XML and make sure you have sdk updated to android O

Comment: but, i am able to set font this way in other widgets..

Comment: see you have to options , either create a customize adapter by inheriting the array adapter with your approach or follow the approach in my answer , though i won't be able to post working demo of mentioned approach till tomorrow due to some issues

Answer (score 1):

You can create a customize `item.xml` layout with [`fonts in XML`](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/fonts-in-xml.html) which has backward compatibility till API 14

and use [`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[])) constructor

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation is don't.
Use a solution like Calligraphy to handle custom face fonts.
https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy